# Validation for double and Integer

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

This is my code. I want to check if the input is either double or int.. it doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't work like I wanted it to be. Any help will be appreciated. the code was not yet finished please dont mind the computation.. (Sorry for my grammar)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number1 = 0;
        double numb2 = 0;
        int number3 = 0;
        try{
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount to be deposited each month: ");
        String num1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
        String num2 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the month you plan to save: ");
        String num3 = scan.nextLine();
       if(scan.hasNext()){
             number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
             numb2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Invalid response! Please enter a number. /n");
       }
       if(scan.hasNext()){
              number3 =  Integer.parseInt(num3);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Invalid response! Please enter a number. /n");
       }
       
       double ans = number1 + numb2 + number3;
       
       System.out.println(ans);
       
       

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
    }
}
```

I also try doing this but it does the same.

```
 if(scan.hasNextDouble() || scan.hasNextInt()){
             number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
             numb2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
             number3 =  Integer.parseInt(num3);
           
       }else{
           System.out.println("Invalid response! Please enter a number. /n");
       }
```

Comment: Using scan.hasNextDouble() || scan.hasNextInt() seems to be a proper way, what exactly is not working?

Comment: usually it is better to be more specific than just "doesn't work like I wanted it to be" - not only explain exactly what you want (is OK in this question) but also explain what it is doing (how that is wrong) including input/output examples

Comment: `if (num1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) { number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1); }` Validates a string entry for a signed or unsigned Integer or Floating Point numerical value.